# How to write JUnit test of a class that uses anonymous inner class such as PreparedStatementSetter?

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

I have the following class that uses an anonymous inner class (`new PreparedStatementSetter()`) to set values in the query using a `PreparedStatementSetter` and returns a `List` of object.

The problem is that I am not sure how to write unit test for this kind of method. 
As soon as my unit test reaches the line where it calls `getJdbcTemplate().query(......)` it jumps to the end of line and `discAuditLogList` value returns `null` and unit test finishes without any errors. 
When I look at the code coverage in `IntelliJ` all the `ps.setString` statements never got executed.

**ProductLogDao.java**

```
//bunch of setter getters here

public List<ProductLogDTO> getProductLogDetail(RequestDTO requestDTO) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
    logger.info("Inside ProductLogDao.getProductLogDetail" + requestDTO);
    List<ProductLogDTO> productLogList = null;
    final Map<String, String> requestParamMap = requestDTO.getParameters();
    if ("custom".equalsIgnoreCase(requestParamMap.get("recordtype"))) {
        ProductLogList = getProductCustomDetail(senderFeeSql, requestParamMap);
        return ProductLogList;
    }
    return productLogList;
}


public List<ProductLogDTO> getProductCustomDetail(String senderFeeSql,
                                                          final Map<String, String> requestParamMap) throws SQLException {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<ProductLogDTO> productLogList = getJdbcTemplate().query(senderFeeSql, new PreparedStatementSetter() {
        public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
            /***************************************************************************************************************/
            //FOLLOWING STATMENTS NEVER GET EXECUTED BECAUSE THEY ARE WITHIN ANONYMOUS CLASS (new PreparedStatementSetter())
            /***************************************************************************************************************/
            ps.setString(1, requestParamMap.get("startDfId"));
            ps.setString(2, requestParamMap.get("startDfId"));
            ps.setString(3, requestParamMap.get("chanelId"));
            ps.setString(4, requestParamMap.get("chanelId"));
            ps.setString(5, requestParamMap.get("fromDateTime"));
            ps.setString(6, requestParamMap.get("toDateTime"));
            ps.setString(7, requestParamMap.get("fromDateTime"));
            ps.setString(8, requestParamMap.get("toDateTime"));
        }
    }, new ProductCustomRowMapper());

    if (null != productLogList && (productLogList.size() > 0)) {
        productLogList.get(0).setRecordtype("custom");
        productLogList.get(0).setRecordsFetched(productLogList.get(0).getRecordsFetched());
    }
    return productLogList;
}
```

**ProductLogDaoTest.java**

```
public class ProductLogDaoTest {

    ProductLogDao instance = new ProductLogDao();
    RequestDTO requestDTO = Mockito.mock(RequestDTO.class);
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = Mockito.mock(JdbcTemplate.class);
    Map<String, String> requestParamMap = new HashMap<>();

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        instance.setJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);
    }

    @Test
    public void getProductLogDetail_W_Custom() throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
        when(requestDTO.getParameters()).thenReturn(requestParamMap);
        requestParamMap.put("recordtype", "custom");
        assertNotNull(instance.getProductLogDetail(requestDTO));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Never create an object instance inside in the dependent object like this: `new PreparedStatementSetter()`
It wires this class instance hardly and you unable to change it to a mock. 
Always do one of these:

1. Create these class instances by a factory object method call (myBusinessFactoryInstance.createPreparedStatementSetter). Than you can create a mock if you change the factory.
2. In Spring you can inject this dependency by constructor or setter method.

If you do so your testing will be like a charm.

Comment: Thanks @The Bitman, any pointers on how to implement your suggestions?

Comment: 1., Investigate the `Abstract Factory` and the `Factory method` design patterns. 2., Read some books about base Spring mechanisms.  It is too long to write detailed suggestions. Learn about `SOLID` modelling principles, the `Clean Code`, etc. Rober Cecil Martin as an author is a very good source of knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You have mocked `JdbcTemplate`, but haven't mocked your `JdbcTemplate` methods. That's why it returns null.

You can use some kind of test database. In case of Spring you can use embedded ones: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M4/spring-framework-reference/html/ch12s08.html. Please refer to this question for more information about simulating database during tests: [How to simulate a DB for testing (Java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928760/how-to-simulate-a-db-for-testing-java)

Either way you can check whether or not your `query()` method was called with Mockito's `verify()` method.